# How to check output voltages?

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, output

I'm attempting to repair a Dell P2210 PC monitor. I've traced the fault to a faulty diode on the power supply board. As part of the repair I would like to check the output voltages. The service manual mentions both 12v and 5v but it's a 12 pin connector so I'm not quite sure where exactly I check for the voltages.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your schematic looks like it's missing a slice off the right-hand side which would show you where the pins on that header connect.

Comment: @brhans, yes, that does seem to be the case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the bits that are truncated to the right in that service manual you copied, the right hand connector is numbered 1..12 from top to bottom like the other connectors  (also notice the three orphaned '1' characters at the bottom).

So the first 4 pins (1 to 4) are 5V, the next two (5 and 6) are GND and the remaining 6 pins are control signals.

The bottom (pin 12) appears to knock the 5V down to a lower voltage for some reason (when pulled low, but not when open).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although brhans is right, you can still find the voltages by simple continuity checks:

- It should be easy to find the GND/return of DC outputs because it's common for all.
- Find C881 on the board and check continuity between its positive terminal and the respective connector terminals. You'll find 12V output.
- Repeat the step above for C875 for 5V.

If the designators are not printed on the board or are unreadable then you can try guessing by comparing the values on the schematic to the ones on the board. For example, if you can see two back to back 470u/25V electrolytic caps then they are probably the output caps of the 12V line.

Comment: Hi @Rohat Kılıç, could you please explain the process for finding GND/return?

Comment: @jrcollins it's generally a large copper pour covering all the secondary side. And also, all of the electrolytics (the ones closer to the output connector) have their negative terminals connected to GND/return.